# C# - Compile variable as name/code

Tags: c#, variables, compilation

Since I couldn't explain very good in my last question and I didn't get an answer that could satisfy me, I decided to open a new one.
 Straight to the point, what I'm basically trying to do is compiling a variable (the value it holds) as a part of code (and specificly in my case referencing another variable)
Say I have:

```
int var_1, var_2, var_3 ... var_10;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var_%i%=20; //if i is 1, then var_1's value will be set to 20, if i is 2, then var_2's value will be set to 20. So basically this loop sets the value of var_1 .. var_10 to 20
}
```

I can explain in an even simpler way, if in any case the latter is not clear.

```
int var_5;
int SomeOtherVar = 5;
var_%SomeOtherVar% = 10; // so var_5 (where 5 is the value of SomeOtherVar) is set to 10
```

Is this doable and if it is, what's the approach?

Comment: No, it's not doable, next.

Comment: I had exactly the same idea when I was new to programming. It might seem like a ridiculous question to a pro but I can relate to this. +1

Comment: Well, I can't blame people for thinking about this. It's not an illogical conclusion when you only know about the existence of scalar variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do that, why dont you use an array?

```
    int[]  array = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = 20;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doable. Use an array instead. The type is `int[]` but I suggest you go read a tutorial about arrays to understand how to create and use them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a situation where you'd need to do this. If you wish to store values against a consecutive list of numbers, use an array. Otherwise you could use a Dictionary. For example to store "var1" = 20, "var2" = 20 as in your question, you could do this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    dict.Add("var" + i.ToString(), 20);
}
```

Some examples of usage:

```
dict["var1"]              // 20
dict["var2"]              // 20
dict.ContainsKey("var3")  // true
dict.ContainsKey("var99") // false
```

Note: I'm concatenating the string "var" with the int from the loop just to demonstrate that you can use arbitary strings as keys to store / lookup the values. In this case it's a bit of a strange thing to do, and you'd probably be best sticking to a normal array, but my example shows how a dictionary could work with more complex keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass static type checking and you feel like creating some coding horror, you can use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) combined with the `dynamic` keyword. Won't let you set variables in your scope, but will technically let you declare your own ones. Note that in my example I cast it to `IDictionary<string, object>` because I create its members' names at runtime from a string. What the following method does is create twenty members and assign their values from 0 to 19.

```
static dynamic SetVariables(IEnumerable<int> range)
{
    const string variableName = "var_";
    var expandoDictionary = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach (var i in range)
        expandoDictionary[variableName + i] = i;
    return expandoDictionary;
}
```

You can then access the members easily this way:

```
var container = SetVariables(Enumerable.Range(0, 20));
var value13 = container.var_13;
```

Please note that I **do not** recommend this usage, and I'd stay away from `dynamic` as much as I can. However, for the sake of problem solving, this can be seen as one unsafe but partial solution.